# not able to copy data from one table to another in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am using new installed sql server 2008

i am trying to copy data from one table to another..i wrote query like this;

```
insert into Clr  select * from Color_tbl
```

but this is showing error like this:

**Invalid object name 'Clr'.**

what i have to do? i have change any setting?

**clr is not an existing table..i hop if i execute this query that will create clr table automatically...**

I used to copy data from one table to another table like this: but i dont know what happend after installing new Sql server??

any help is very appriciable

Comment: i want to copy Color_tbl data to clr table?

Comment: Are you in the correct database? You can use  this command to be sure: "USE yourDatabase". Also, always put the object schema in front of it, like dbo.Clr or custom.Clr.

Comment: am in correct database only

Comment: i tryed all this..but still showing same error

Comment: i want to know i have to change anything in settings

Comment: Next time, please state **ALL** the relevant info when writing the question. Without that, it's a waste of time both for you and us.

Comment: sorry for that...i wont repeat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything else about your database and schemas, you could try using fully qualified names, like so:

```
INSERT INTO [DBContainingClr].[SchemaContainingClr].Clr
SELECT * FROM [DBContainingColor_tbl].[SchemaContainingColor_tbl].Color_tbl
```

UPDATE: OP has clarified that he is in fact trying to **CREATE** the table `Clr`, and it doesn't exist at the moment. In which case the syntax should be:

```
SELECT * INTO Clr FROM Color_Tbl
```

Comment: but now showing error:Invalid object name 'DBContainingColor_tbl.SchemaContainingColor_tbl.Color_tbl'.

Comment: I'm hoping you replaced those with the actual DB and Schema names?

Comment: DBContainingClr=>i can give dbname.SchemaContainingClr=> what i have to give?

Comment: Have you created separate schemas in your DB? If not, you can use `dbo` for schema.

Comment: i given like this:INSERT INTO Vallett.dbo.Clr
SELECT * FROM Vallett.dbo.Color_tbl

Comment: Should be correct if your DB name is Vallett, and you haven't created any schemas.

Comment: but still am getting error:Invalid object name 'Vallett.dbo.Clr'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52725/discussion-between-shree-pat18-and-user3252014)

Comment: i dont know what is the Schemas? i dont think i created any schemas?